# Use cache in apollo client

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

I try to read data from apollo cache (React + Apollo Client 2.6).

My code:

```
try {
    const {users} = client.readQuery({
        query: GetUsersForView
    });

    console.log(users);
}
catch(e) {
    console.log('Query is not in cache:', e);
}
```

My query:

```
query GetUsersForView($search : String, $country_id : [ID]) {
    users (
        filters : {
            search: $search
            country: $country_id
        }) {
        ...BasicData
        country {
            ...BasicData
        }
    }
}
```

Result in the console:

```
Query is not in cache: Invariant Violation: Can't find field users({"filters":{}}) on object {
  "authenticatedUser": {…},
  "userSettings": {…},
  "users({\"filters\":{\"country\":[],\"search\":\"\"}})": [
    {…},
    {…},
    {…}
  ],
  "countries": [
    {…},
    {…},
    {…},
    {…}
  ]
}.
```

What I am doing wrong? 
Results of the query is in the cache, so why I cannot retrieve the data?

Answer (score 0):

This snippet shows that it's looking for `users({"filters":{}})` in the cache:

```
Query is not in cache: Invariant Violation: Can't find field users({"filters":{}}) on object {
  "authenticatedUser": {…},
  "userSettings": {…},
  "users({\"filters\":{\"country\":[],\"search\":\"\"}})": [
    {…},
    {…},
    {…}
  ],
  "countries": [
    {…},
    {…},
    {…},
    {…}
  ]
}.
```

but you can see 4 lines below that, that your cache instead contains the key `users({\"filters\":{\"country\":[],\"search\":\"\"}})`

- It looks like you aren't passing variables to the query in your example. Previously in your app somewhere they had been queried & stored in your cache by calling the query with the following variables:

```
{
   country: [],
   search: ""
}
```

and so, you must pass these along again to allow apollo to find it in the cache, like this (adapting your first snippet):

```
try {
    const {users} = client.readQuery({
        query: GetUsersForView,
         variables: {
           country: [],
           search: ":
         },
    });

    console.log(users);
}
catch(e) {
    console.log('Query is not in cache:', e);
}
```